# Get d from Free space path loss equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

How would I get $d$ from this: $L = 10 n \log_{10}(d)+C$.

I've got this so far:

$$\begin{aligned}
L-C &= 10n \log_{10}(d)\\
\frac{L-C}{10n} &= \log_{10}(d)
\end{aligned}$$

Is it: $2^{10}\cdot \frac{L-C}{10n} = d$ ????

Comment: What are $n$ and $C$ ? Known parameters ?

Comment: Hi, I took the liberty of reformatting your question using LaTeX. Could you please check that I did not introduce any errors?

Answer (score 1):

Exponentiate both sides: $$\frac{L-C}{10n} = \log_{10}(d) \Leftrightarrow 10^{\frac{L-C}{10n}} = 10^{\log_{10}(d)} = d$$

Comment: So to confirm (my maths is very primitive) `d = 10*(L-C/10n)`

Comment: If by $*$ you mean ^, and by $L-C/10n$ you mean $(L-C)/(10n)$, yes.